# Change the color of a single cell (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, json, tableview, cell

I have a tableview with json and I would like for example if my label = France to the cell of a different color, is it possible? how?

Comment: How are you creating your cells ?

Comment: Well it's depends how the data is stored.  But basically in the relevant data source method, where you create the cells, you examine the data and do different things based on different data values.

Comment: Show us your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` Method please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, here is a minimalist example, using UITableViewController. Ideally there shouldn't be too much logic in your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method, but this is just a simple example.

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) NSArray *countriesArray;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }
    _countriesArray = @[@"France", @"Germany", @"Spain", @"Norway", @"Denmark", @"United States"];
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.countriesArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([self.countriesArray[indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"France"]) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = self.countriesArray[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```